# Is it appropriate to deny the right to vote for a person?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, voting

Why are users with less than 125 reputation not allowed to cast their vote? Don't they have right to express their feelings?

Comment: If you want to express your feelings for this site, contribute! Ask and answer questions, propose edits, etc.

Comment: Note also that there should not be any expectations of doing what you want with someone else's software. It's their stuff and they'll let you use it if you follow their rules.

Comment: @KyleKanos And that's why we call them privileges.

Comment: huh? voting has nothing to do with feelings. If you actually vote out of feelings, I have to say I'm glad you are not allowed to!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users with over just **25** reputation are allowed to cast *upvotes*.

It is only *downvoting* that requires 125 reputation.

There are good reasons for this, primarily, it's because the SE think's it's more beneficial to focus on upvotes as you are still becoming used to the community.  It should take some time for you to recognize how the community functions, what is good content, and what is bad content in the SE format.

The site is community driven, so the members who primarily drive the voting process should at least be users familiar enough to gain 125 rep somehow.

But most importantly, as outlined in the Help Centre, [Downvoting is a privilege](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), not a right.  It is one of [many privileges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) that are earned as you become more familiar with the site.

The downvoting privilege page I linked also gives good advice for what to do instead of downvoting:

> What are the alternatives to down-voting?
>
> The up-vote privilege comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top. Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.
>
> Instead of voting down:
>
> - If the post is spammy or offensive, flag it.
> - If the question is duplicate or off-topic, flag it for moderator attention.
> - If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at your answer, I think I may have been hasty in swapping the 'downvote' tag for 'voting' tag; it does seem OP is intending to downvote.

Comment: It is probably worth adding that *all* users can cast the accept "vote" on answer to questions that they asked.